# Unable to create a .mplstyle for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to create my own .mplstyle file.
I wrote all the parameters into a txt file, and save it with a name ending with '.mplstyle'.
However Windows recognise it as a txt file, not a .mplstyle.
I tried to set the style in a jupyter notebook with the command:

```
plt.style.use('my_style_paper')
```

but I get the error:
''my_style' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles'

How do I create a .mplstyle file?

Answer (score 0):

Is your .mplstyle file in the same working directory as your program? If not, then you would have to specify the path inside `plt.style.use("path")` for example, './Documents/presentation.mplstyle'

Comment: the file is in the same directory as the other .mplstyle file. The problem is that I do not know how to create a file with extension .mplstyle.

Comment: Try using notepad++ and saving the file using the .mplstyle extension?